# Point and Array game Java

Tags: java, arrays, cmd, point

I am to create a game in cmd (not gui) in java, its a larger project, but for now, I'd love to know how would I create a 12x12 grid, spawn a player at 0,0 (left top corner) and move him around using keys?

I have attempted to create an array, but didn't seem to get movement to work. I'm a newbie, so would welcome any suggestions.

```
package hunters;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*; 
import java.awt.*;


public class Hunters {

        private static int score;
       private static String player = "P";
       private static String move;
     private static   String emptyfield = "X";
     private static   String [][]a2 = new String [12][12];
 private static int pr,cr;

 public static void paint_board(){
for (int r = 0 ; r < a2.length; r++){
    for (int c= 0; c <a2[r].length; c++){
        a2 [r][c] = emptyfield;
        a2[pr][cr] = player;
        System.out.print(" "+a2[r][c]);
    }
  System.out.println("");

}
  }
  public static void main(String[] args){

      Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
score = 0;

 paint_board();
 do{
System.out.println("Input your move");

move = in.nextLine();
if (move.equalsIgnoreCase("w")){
 //move up
   a2[pr-1][cr]= player;
    //repaint
   paint_board();
    //check for collision
    //check for health

}else if(move.equalsIgnoreCase("s")){
    //move down
    a2[pr+1][cr]= player;
    //repaint
    paint_board();
      //check for collision
    //check for health

}else if(move.equalsIgnoreCase("d")){
    //move right
    a2[pr][cr+1] = player;
    //repaint
    paint_board();
      //check for collision
    //check for health

}else if(move.equalsIgnoreCase("a")){
    //move left
    a2[pr][cr-1]=player;
    //repaint
    paint_board();
      //check for collision
    //check for health

}
}while(score !=5);
}   
}
```

this is the way i'd like it to work. I have tried to create a separate Position class but I have failed in the process...`

Comment: Think about your model.  You might have something like new Room[12][12] array where the Room can have a Player object.  Moving will require some some simple arithmetic and out of bounds checks.  Post some code of what you have and we can help solve your movement problem.

Comment: @ChrisArom: While you should post code, you should post code that most succinctly conveys the intent of the question.  I'd recommend trying to reduce the unnecessary code to better get your point across and make this a better question.

Answer (score 1):

Create a 2D array, have a way to paint a cell in the 2D array (which might contain different objects as defined by the value of the cell). So you might check the square to paint, and if the value is HUMAN (pre-defined constant) then draw a human at that location on the screen.

```
void paint_cell(int x, int y) {
  if (array[x][y] == HUMAN) {
   printf("H");
  } else if (array[x][y] == ENEMY) {
    printf("E");
  } else if (array[x][y] == EMPTY) {
    printf(" ");
  }
}

void paint_maze() {
   for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {
       printf("|");
       for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
          paint_cell(i,j);
       }
       printf("|\n");
   }
}
```

When you receive a key event, go to the cell that contains the human and move it to a new destination depending on the key. Then draw the maze again.

Comment: I think I have an idea of how to move a player around, however, I cannot get an idea of how to re-paint the array after each move.

Comment: It might just be H for human, space for empty, E for enemy. You can draw horizontal sides with '-' and verticals with '|'.

Comment: I've got P for player, H for Hunter, and emptyspace is X ( Attached a code to the main post )

Comment: I have added the paint_maze example, you might also want to clear screen before each paint. JCurses might be of help.

Comment: I have my array in the main method, would a good solution be to create a separate class for the board display, and try to repaint it with something like Board.display ? Or do I have to include my print array code in every single movement event? Thanks

Comment: It is better to have the methods encapsulated in a class. However, even using a function like paint_maze above, you can just call the function rather than repeating the code.

Comment: Added my current code, while loop allows me for multiple entries and the board resets fine, however my P stays in the same place, is the player row(int pr) and player column(pc) a good solution, or did i miss something there?

Comment: Fixed, a player can be now moved throughout the array, thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

"An Array" is definitely the right idea -- a two-dimensional array is probably what I would use to contain the spaces of the grid.  But -- what is going to be in the array? Objects that represent the spaces that the user moves through?  That's cool; you will have to figure out how to define those spaces, and figure out how to display each one on the screen.

You probably can't use a `KeyListener` to check for user keystrokes, since `KeyListener` is part of AWT/Swing, but you will need a way to get input from the keyboard.  Reading from `stdin` is the easy way to go here.  You will need to run a loop that listens for user input at the keyboard, and moves the user's "gamepiece" from square to square depending on which key they hit.

Comment: The whole project will consist of a player trying to avoid NPC's (hunters) that spawn at 12,12 and move toward 0,0 using pre-defined path. Player losses HP when collision happens with hunter etc.

Comment: That sounds great -- but you're going to need to work through the very most basic parts of this first.  You can't have the hunters moving around the maze until you define the maze.

Comment: Maze is defined as an 12x12 array already. It prints 24 X's, and a P at 0,0. Now the movement part is needed.